# TextBox.Enter() Event fires Textbox.Leave() Event with it in WinForm

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2019

I'm making Signup form using WinForms of C#.
I have made 2 private functions to call for `Enter()` and `Leave()` Events in different `TexBox.Enter()`
 and `TexBox.Leave()` Events.

```
private void EnterBox(TextBox Box, string Text, PictureBox PicBox, Bitmap Pic, Label WarningLabel)
{
    if ((Box.Text == Text) && (Box.TextAlign == HorizontalAlignment.Center))
    {
        Box.Clear();

        if (Box == PassBox)
            Box.UseSystemPasswordChar = true;
        Box.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
    }
    PicBox.BackgroundImage = Pic;
    WarningLabel.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(34, 36, 49);
    Box.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(78, 184, 206);
}

private void LeaveBox(TextBox Box, string Text, PictureBox PicBox, Bitmap Pic, Label WarningLabel)
{
    if (Box.Text == "")
    {
        if (Box == PassBox)
            Box.UseSystemPasswordChar = false;

        WarningLabel.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        Box.Text = Text;
        Box.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
        Box.ForeColor = Color.Gray;
    }
    else
    {
        if (!Regex.IsMatch(Box.Text, (string)Box.Tag))
            WarningLabel.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        Box.ForeColor = Color.White;
    }
    PicBox.BackgroundImage = Pic;
    Box.Select(0, 0);                     // Move the Cursor to Start.
}
```

It seems to work fine with other TextBoxes but it does not work fine with PassBox.

```
private void PassBox_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    EnterBox(PassBox, "Password", PasswordPic, Properties.Resources.password__2_, PasswordWarningLabel);
}

private void PassBox_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LeaveBox(PassBox, "Password", PasswordPic, Properties.Resources.password, PasswordWarningLabel);
}
```

Debuging it with `VS-Studio-2019` shows When I enter the `EnterBox()` of `PassBox_Enter()` after Compeleting the

```
if ((Box.Text == Text) && (Box.TextAlign == HorizontalAlignment.Center))
    {
        Box.Clear();

        if (Box == PassBox)
            Box.UseSystemPasswordChar = true;
        Box.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
    }
```

it enters the `PassBox_Leave()` and execute it then again it enters the `PassBox_Enter()` and execute the function again.

I was working fine but all of sudden it started to do so.
I tried to delete the previous TexBox and again generating another box but it stared to do so again.

Comment: The UseSystemPasswordChar property is a "difficult" property, it requires Winforms to recreate the native textbox control.  If you look closely you ought to see it flicker.  That has side-effects if the control has the focus.  Avoid trouble by setting the property in the constructor or the designer.

Comment: I can't reproduce. You should try create new simple Win Form (minimum controls)  and paste designer code. May be simplify it.

Comment: I would check to make sure the correct events are registered to the correct event handlers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in the line

```
if (Box == PassBox)
            Box.UseSystemPasswordChar = true;
```

in the `EnterBox` method. When you call `Box.UseSystemPasswordChar = true;` you set the `TextBox` to restricted mode (as you can read under important [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textbox.usesystempasswordchar?view=netframework-4.8)). When the `TextBox` is put in restricted mode it loses the focus and the `PassBox_Leave` event will be thrown. This is the reason why the debug behaves as you described.

If you want to make sure that the `PassBox_Entered` event is completed before any call to `PassBox_Leave` is made you have to make sure that no line of code in `EnterBox` is switching the focus from the `TextBox`. This is currently made by the line `Box.UseSystemPasswordChar = true;` in `EnterBox`.

However they are ways to circumvent this problem by for example boolean flags. This solution may not be optimal but should work.

Since `PassBox_Leave` may be called by either `Box.UseSystemPasswordChar = true;` (where you do not want anything in `LeaveBox` to be executed) or when the user leaves the `TextBox` (where you want `LeaveBox` to execute) you can use a boolean flag in your class and set it to `true` before the line `Box.UseSystemPasswordChar = true;` in `EnterBox` is executed. Then in the first rows of `LeaveBox` you check if the boolean flag is `true` and if it is you return, hence nothing in `LeaveBox` will be executed (however `PassBox_Leave` will still be called, therefore this might not be an optimal solution).

```
Public Class YourClass {
    private bool falseCall; //Add this boolean flag as an attribute to your class

    public YourClass() {
       falseCall = false; //Set the inital value to false in the constructor of your class;
    }

    private void EnterBox(TextBox Box, string Text, PictureBox PicBox, Bitmap Pic, Label WarningLabel)
    {

       if ((Box.Text == Text) && (Box.TextAlign == HorizontalAlignment.Center))
       {
           Box.Clear();

           if (Box == PassBox) {
              falseCall = true; //Set the flag to true before the call to LeaveBox is executed
              Box.UseSystemPasswordChar = true;
           }
           Box.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
       }
    //-------Rest of method-----------
    }


    private void LeaveBox(TextBox Box, string Text, PictureBox PicBox, Bitmap Pic, Label WarningLabel)
    {
        if(falseCall) { 
            falseCall = false; //Reset the boolean flag 
            return; 
        }
        //--------Rest of method-----------
    }
}
```

So basically the program will still enter `LeaveBox` when `Box.UseSystemPasswordChar = true;` is executed but it will quickly return since the flag was set to true. When the user leaves the `TextBox` the flag will be false and `LeaveBox` will be executed as intended.

Comment: I was working fine but it started to do so all of a sudden. Is there any way around that I don't have to change my code
`if (Box == PassBox)
            Box.UseSystemPasswordChar = true;`

Comment: No, having the code left in `EnterBox` will switch the focus from the `TextBox` making the call to the `PassBox_Leave` event. You  can solve it by moving the code to either the constructor or the designer of the `TextBox`. How are your `TextBox` intended to work? Do you always want it to display the text as the default password character (i.e. always hide it) or do you want the user to be able to see the inputed password in the `TextBox`?

Comment: Well, the thing is I want to show the user that this block is for a password by `PassBox.Text = "Password ";` but when the user enters the box it should remove the text and make the  `Box.UseSystemPasswordChar = true;` and take the input as such it is. But if the user leaves the box empty it should make this command `PassBox.Text = "Password";` and then ` Box.UseSystemPasswordChar = false;`

Comment: I have edited my inital answer to give you a possible solution to your problem, check it out.

Comment: Well, I removed the `if (Box == PassBox) Box.UseSystemPasswordChar = true;` from `LeaveBox()` and `EnterBox()` event and place it `if (Box == PassBox) Box.UseSystemPasswordChar = true;` before calling this functions in `PassBox_Enter()` and `PassBox_Leave()` Funtions and it worked Fine.

Comment: Your idea was also good but in my case, I don't need to use any Flag and it works fines. I think now I am ready to close this question. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Perfect, you are most welcome! I thought you did not want to move `if (Box == PassBox) Box.UseSystemPasswordChar = true;` from `EnterBox` hence my answer is more complicated.

Comment: It was of great help to understand it's working. And I did not want to remove it but open to any suggestion about placing it somewhere else as long as it works.

Answer (score 1):

As @Hans Passant and @[MarkusAnd](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60988955?noredirect=1) said changing the `UseSystemPasswordChar` triggers the `PassBox_Leave()` event each time. I removed the `if (Box == PassBox) Box.UseSystemPasswordChar = true;` and `if (Box == PassBox) Box.UseSystemPasswordChar = false;` from `LeaveBox()` and `EnterBox()` and updated `PassBox_Enter()` and `PassBox_Leave()` as follow

```
private void PassBox_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 if (PassBox.TextAlign == HorizontalAlignment.Center)
    PassBox.UseSystemPasswordChar = true;
 EnterBox(PassBox, "Password", PasswordPic, Properties.Resources.password__2_, PasswordWarningLabel);
}
```

and

```
private void PassBox_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 if (PassBox.Text == "")
     PassBox.UseSystemPasswordChar = false;
 LeaveBox(PassBox, "Password", PasswordPic, Properties.Resources.password, PasswordWarningLabel);
}
```

It will still trigger the `PassBox_Leave()` but it will work.